# What is the version of OData protocol used in Azure Mobile Services

Tags: asp.net, azure, odata, azure-mobile-services

I am unable to find any information on the supported version from MSDN.

Comment: Hi, does my answer clarify your question?

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure that it is v3.

This page https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/mobile-services-html-how-to-use-client-library/ links to the v3 spec here:

> For more information on OData system query options, see the OData system query options reference.

Just in case that link was out of date and they have now upgraded, I checked the documentation and it has things that aren't in v4.

Answer (score 1):

I got a confirmed answer from Microsoft yesterday.

[Answer on MSDN Azure Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e9dbbc7c-6cc9-4277-ab12-eb4b03fdfd02/what-are-the-versions-of-odata-protocol-supported-in-azure-mobile-services?forum=azuremobile)

> It's mostly v3.  You can find details on the OData query specification
> here:
> http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/url-conventions/#url5.1
>
> Adrian Hall - Microsoft (MSFT)

Hope this helps!